# pass a Type as an attribute argument

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

i want to have some class like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = typeof(T).Name + "List")]
public class EntityListBase<T> where T : EntityBase, new()
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(T).Name)]
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

but typeof(T) cannot be attribute argument.

what can i do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `XmlAttributeOverrides` - BUT - be careful to cache and re-use the serializer instance:

```
static void Main()
{
    var ser = SerializerCache<Foo>.Instance;
    var list = new EntityListBase<Foo> {
        Items = new List<Foo> {
            new Foo { Bar = "abc" }
    } };
    ser.Serialize(Console.Out, list);
}
static class SerializerCache<T> where T : EntityBase, new()
{
    public static XmlSerializer Instance;
    static SerializerCache()
    {
        var xao = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        xao.Add(typeof(EntityListBase<T>), new XmlAttributes
        {
            XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name + "List")
        });
        xao.Add(typeof(EntityListBase<T>), "Items", new XmlAttributes
        {
            XmlElements = { new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(T).Name) }
        });
        Instance = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EntityListBase<T>), xao);
    }
}
```

(if you don't cache and re-use the serializer instance, it will leak assemblies)

Comment: note that using generic classes will bypass "static". and cache data is practically useless in this case.

Comment: @Rzassar you are mistaken. The generic is very deliberate as a simple mechanism o have one serializer per type/T. The cache is ***essential*** when using XmlAttributeOverrides - as I explained: otherwise you will leak assemblies. Assemblies from this approach **cannot be collected**. If you use the simpler constructors, it caches internally. But with the more exotic constructor of XmlSerializer you (the caller) need to handle that.